# Are double-slash comments valid in CSS?

Tags: css, comments

How reliable is using a double-slash (`//`) for a single-line comment in CSS? Are they part of the CSS specification? Do most mainstream browsers or CSS interpreters support them?

Comment: mmh not reliable at all? css comment is `/* comment */`

Comment: 0%. It's not valid CSS comment syntax at all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments

Comment: Yes I know the CSS syntax, thats not what i was asking for. The fact that // working as single-line comment in CSS, but can you rely on browsers to understand that´s a comment...

Comment: No, `//` doesn't work as a CSS comment. Period. All you're seeing is the browser failing to understand what you've entered. It's being treated as a mistake, not a comment, the same way `xyzbackground: red;` would be ignored.

Comment: What an unusual question.

Comment: Aactually @j08691 the double slash will not be treaded the same way as the misspell you mentioned. Not in browser dev-console anyway... It will be treated as a comment as far as I can see?

Comment: This is a mega duplicate. What is the canonical question?

Comment: A candidate (2010): *[Why do /**/ comments work in stylesheets but // comments don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479351/why-do-comments-work-in-stylesheets-but-comments-dont)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do /\*\*/ comments work in stylesheets, but // comments don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479351/why-do-comments-work-in-stylesheets-but-comments-dont)

Comment: @PeterMortensen What, exactly, is a 'mega' duplicate as opposed to an ordinary duplicate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Comments using double slashes `//` are invalid in CSS.  The [CSS spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#consume-comments) states only the following about comments:

> **4.3.2. Consume comments**
>
> This section describes how to ***consume comments*** from a stream of
> code points. It returns nothing.
>
> If the next two input code point are U+002F SOLIDUS (/) followed by a
> U+002A ASTERISK (*), consume them and all following code points up to
> and including the first U+002A ASTERISK (*) followed by a U+002F
> SOLIDUS (/), or up to an EOF code point. Return to the start of this
> step.
>
> If the preceding paragraph ended by consuming an EOF code point, this
> is a parse error.
>
> Return nothing.

In other words, only `/* */` are valid comments. The spec does not mention `//`.

However, `//` **is** valid in certain CSS processors such as [Less](http://lesscss.org/#comments) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments).

---

Per your comment:

> ...can you rely on browsers to understand that's a comment

No, the browser will attempt to interpret the syntax anyway and likely fail the rule based on it being a **syntax error** rather than it being a comment.  The result will likely fail based on browser, but using it brings you into undefined behavior.

### Browser Behavior with Double Slash Comments

Here are the results of the following rules being applied in different browsers.  One styling uses the double slash at the beginning of the property, and one has the `//` right before the value.

```css
#some {
    width: 500px;
    /*height: 400px;*/
    //color: blue;
    background-color: //red;
}
```

#### Firefox

[image: Firefox Elements Panel]

In **Firefox ESR 52.9.0**, you get a little yellow warning triangle next to `color` and `background-color` because `//color` is an invald CSS property and because `//red` is an invalid `background-color` value.

#### Chrome

[image: Chrome Elements Panel]

Interestingly, in **Chrome 68.0.3440.106**, I don't even see the `//color: blue` show up in the elements panel which might mean that Chrome tries to consider the line a comment, but since `//` being comments is not in the spec, you should not rely on it.  However, `background-color` also has the warning since `//red` is an invalid value.

#### Safari

[image: Safari Elements Panel]

**Safari 11.1.2** has the same behavior as Chrome where the `//` led property is not even listed and the `//` led value is a syntax error.

#### Internet Explorer 11

[image: IE11 Elements Panel]

**Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.19080** considers the entirety of `//color: blue` to be the rule property and believes it has no value as though you had written `//color: blue: ;`.  It also lists `background-color: //red` but considers it an error and does not apply it.

---

It should also be noted that for the following:

```css
#some {
    // width: 400px;
    /* height: 400px; */
}
```

Most of the browsers will at least acknowledge the `/* */` property and allow you to toggle it in the Dev tools.  For Chrome and Safari, the `//` led rule isn't even listed meaning you **can't** toggle it as you could with the `/* */`.

Comment: Thank you, as you say chrome seems to handle it as a proper comment. I know thats is not proper css-syntax, and I´m not using today.

Comment: @Kalabalik I didn't say that, I said that it doesn't even acknowledge the `//` led property in the panel.  It will at least list `/* */` properties in the panel and allow you to toggle them.  I would really advise against using `//`.

Comment: But why? Is there a good reason why they're not supported, as in possible conflicting property names, or is it just an arbitrary decision on the RFC? Because CSS being as close as it is to JS, one would expect it to have support for these kind of comments as a matter of convenience.